# hibernate cascade deletion example

Tags: hibernate

can any one provide me full  2 mapping file which implements cascade delete.
measn if A contasis a set of B then when A is deleted B shold automatically be deleted.

Comment: I can only suggest a book NHibernate In Action. They have an example in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need 1 mapping file: the one of the parent object. E.g. this example from [Hibernate in action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193239415X)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-2.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="hello.Message" table="MESSAGES">
    <id
        name="id"
        column="MESSAGE_ID">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property
        name="text"
        column="MESSAGE_TEXT"/>
    <many-to-one
        name="nextMessage"
        cascade="all"
        column="NEXT_MESSAGE_ID"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The "cascade" parameter does the job. If you only want the cascading delete, then you should use cascade="delete". Other options are "all-delete-orphan" and "delete-orphan". Check out the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/) for more info.